# Kendo ui NumericTextBoxFor - Setar valores de inicialização

Tags: .net, kendo-ui

Como posso definir um valor de inicialização padrão para o campo **NumericTextBoxFor** do Kendo.

Ex: Meu campo é inicializado em branco. Quero que ele venha com um default definido por mim:

```
@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(model => model.MinVoltage).Name("MinVoltage").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 6em;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal" }))
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MinVoltage)
```

O meu model está desta forma:

```
    [Column("MIN_VOLTAGE")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Messages), Name = "MinimuVoltage")]
    [Range(0.1, 99.99, ErrorMessage = "Valores válidos: 0.1 a 99.99 ")]
    public double MinVoltage { get; set; }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu defini um valor de Range, e quero que ele inicie por default com o valor 0.1,
Porém o campo é inicializado sem valor default conforme a imagem acima.

Como posso setar um valor de inicialização default para o campo **NumericTextBoxFor**?

Answer (score 0):

Use .Value(0.1) para definir valor padrão.

Para o range use .Min(0.1) e .Max(99.99)

Para configurar o incremento use .Step(0.1)

talvez você tenha que configurar o formato .Format() e caso não consiga com o NumericTextBoxForModel use .NumericTextBox()